# Clipping raster in Python with ArcPy and GDAL using coordinates

Tags: arcpy, python, raster, gdal, clip

I am having trouble clipping a raster with GDAL.  I have the coordinates of the bounding box I would like to clip to. There is no error but also no output file is being saved. Could it have to do with my coordinate system? My coordinates are in a UTM zone (same as raster I am clipping)

```
import arcpy
from arcpy import env
from arcpy.sa import *
import os
import subprocess
import gdal

path = "R:\\Sentinel-1\\kevf\\"
image = "S1A_IW_GRDH_1SDH_20190303T100649_20190303T100714_026172_02EBE6_AD79_out"
segmentedRasterSave = "R:\\Sentinel-1\\kevf\\seg\\S1A_IW_GRDH_1SDH_20190303T100649_20190303T100714_026172_02EBE6_AD79_out_seg.tif"

def split(segmentedRasterSave, image):
    arcpy.CheckOutExtension("Spatial")

    elevRaster = arcpy.sa.Raster(segmentedRasterSave)
    Extent = elevRaster.extent
    #set values
    xL = float(Extent.XMin)
    xR = float(Extent.XMax)

    yB = float(Extent.YMin)
    yT = float(Extent.YMax)

    x_delta = xL - xR
    x1 = xL + float((x_delta/3))
    x2 = xR - float((x_delta/3))

    leftSave = path + "split\\" + "_left.tif"

    ds = gdal.Translate(leftSave, gdal.Open(segmentedRasterSave), projWin = [xL, yB, x1, yT])
    ds = None

split(segmentedRasterSave, image)
```

There is no error message, just no output file is being saved.

Comment: Use os.path.join instead of combining paths like this: `path + "split\\" + "_left.tif"`

Comment: Why arent you using [Clip](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/data-management-toolbox/clip.htm)?

Comment: clip will write out a file that is not clipped to my dimensions.

Comment: clip won't even work on my raster in arcPRO. just returns full extent of input

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [Extract By Mask](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/spatial-analyst/extract-by-mask.htm) tool which:

> Extracts the cells of a raster that correspond to the areas defined by a mask.

The `arcpy` function is:

```py
ExtractByMask(in_raster, in_mask_data)
```

You can convert your bounding box to a shapefile (if you don't have one already) and pass that file as the `in_mask_data` parameter.

Comment: that's what my plan is now. Any suggestions for easily converting a bounding box to a shapefile?

Comment: @Kevin Ferris At the end of the [`arcpy.Polygon`](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/arcpy/classes/polygon.htm) documentation, there is a code sample of how to create  a shapefile from a set of coordinates. You would have to change the points to match your bounding box and set the spatial reference to the UTM zone you are using.

Comment: I keep getting an empty shapefile for whatever reason

Comment: Post a new question with the code you are running and link it here so I can take a look.